# Secondary form freezes from c# backgroundworker

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I have a simple windows form in c# that has a background worker attached to it (simple drag-n-drop from the designer). A few seconds after launching the application a background worker is programmed to start. In the `DoWork()` method I declare a `Form2` object (a simple form that I created with the designer which only has a label on it) and I call `form2.Show()`. The problem is that `form2` freezes as soon as it's shown and I can't understand why. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: It needs to be running on the UI thread.

Comment: Why? Is there no way to show it from another thread? What if I want to animate it?

Comment: It wouldn't help as it uses the same message loop. A truly independant form in another thread would need its own messageloop (for example started with Application.Run()).

Comment: You don't want to have multiple UI threads; trying to manage them is going to be a huge nightmare and the winform framework simply isn't designed to support it in many circumstances.  You're *much* better of simply using a single UI thread and using asynchronous programming methods to avoid blocking the UI thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate(){
            new Form2().Show();
        });
    }
```

Comment: If this is all your BGW is doing there's no point in using a BGW in the first place.  You may as well just run the code right from the UI thread to begin with.

Comment: @Servy is right.
There's no point of doing this, Unless if you're just figuring things out.